# How to search and view docs installed in usr/share/doc

Tags: search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are typical users expected to read the documentation in /usr/share/doc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24072/how-are-typical-users-expected-to-read-the-documentation-in-usr-share-doc)

A way to search and view those docs using web browser is by Installing "dwww" but this needs apache2.2 to run in the back all the time.(It was creating port conflicts and I could not use XAMPP server without removing it.)

Is there any second alternative to view and search these ?

Can I just delete the whole "doc" folder ? Either I want to use them or delete.

Comment: @bodhu: I told here I have used Dwww. It is the best way to view Docs. It comes with "Synaptic Package Manager" as an addon. I want a workaround to dwww or a similar alternative. I dont want to use command line. If I wanted to use commad line then I would go for opening /usr/share/doc and read individual files by opening them with Mousepad.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Apache (either the one from XAMPP or from Ubuntu) on a different port, this is an easy config change.

Info on [Listen directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html)

On my machine, the file which contains the directive is `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`. Just edit it using

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

change port to, say, 88:

```
NameVirtualHost *:88
Listen 88
```

and restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then you can access it at `http://localhost:88/`

Or you can use Ubuntu's Apache and other packages instead of XAMPP - I never understood the need for it on a Linux system anyway.

Comment: @ Sergey: Can u tell me how I can change those configs ? It is very hard for a novice like me to dig around config files and setting them with my exact need.

Comment: It may be difficult to do any web-development without digging in Apache config files :) I've updated the answer.

Comment: @ Sergey: Thanks. Yes you are right. I need to learn about how to work with those config files.

Comment: http://localhost:88/ It says resource not available ?!

Comment: Changing port of apache to 88 makes dwww stop working. Is there any other workaround ?

Comment: `dwww` is just a CGI application, it should not care about at what port Apache runs. Does your Apache start successfully? Are there anything of interest in the error log? What are the symptoms of "stops working"? Other workarounds include 1. using Ubuntu Apache for development instead of XAMPP; 2. configuring XAMPP's Apache to serve `dwww` and not using Ubuntu's Apache and 3. Configuring XAMPP's Apache to use a different port. You can only have one webserver listening on port 80, so you need either to use just one or move the second to another port