# I can't get dwww to work - Keeps getting 404 Not Found

Tags: dpkg, documentation, document-management

When I try to click on a link on the web page produced by dwww - I get the following error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /cgi-bin/dwww/usr/share/doc/ was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) Server at randys-laptop Port 80
```

I've installed the Debian Documentation Browser package.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

`dwww` uses `cgi` to serve the webpages and `cgi` is no longer enabled in `apache2` by default; so you need to enable `cgi`:

```
sudo a2enmod cgi
```

And then restart the `apache2` service with:

```
service apache2 restart
```

That will solve the major problem you are experiencing with `dwww` returning `not found`.

But you might run into another problem. `dwww` allows access from the web server to files in `/var/www/dwww` and `/usr/share/doc` (and it will follow symlinks in other directories to `/usr/share/doc`).

The additional problem you may find is that some of the documentation files are not in `/usr/share/doc`.

For example (this will depend on what documentation you have installed), some directories in `/usr/share/gtk-doc/html` are symlinked to `/usr/share/doc/...`. These will display is `dwww` without problem.

But other files are not and will not display automatically. The `/usr/share/gtk-doc/html/atk` directory, for example, does not use a symlink to `/usr/share/doc`. Trying to open these files with `dwww` results in:

```
dwww will not allow you to read the file /usr/share/gtk-doc/html/atk/index.html
```

There is probably a solution for this involving `apache2`/`dwww` configuration; but I'm no expert in `apache2` security and wouldn't want to introduce a problem.

The simple workaround is to use the `file://` protocol for those (very) few files where you find this problem.

For the `atk` documentation example above, the generated url is:

```
http://<server-name>/cgi-bin/dwww/usr/share/gtk-doc/html/atk/index.html?type=html
```

You can go up to the address bar and edit it to:

```
file:///usr/share/gtk-doc/html/atk/index.html?type=html
```

and the file will then load.

Comment: "The simple workaround is to use the file:// protocol". Why not by  adding symlinks to `/usr/share/doc`?

Answer (score 0):

About the `dwww will not allow you to read ...` issue:

`dwww` will only show files from paths whitelisted in its `DWWW_DOCPATH` setting at `/etc/dwww/dwww.conf`.

The default is `/usr/share/doc:/usr/share/info:/usr/share/man:/usr/local/share/doc:/usr/local/share/info:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/common-licenses`. It does **not** follow symlinks, so you have to manually add their *targets*.