# View info pages in a web browser

Tags: html, info

How do I view info files in a web browser? For man pages you can do **man --html**; is there anything similar for info pages?

I'm aware of makeinfo's ability to output HTML, but to do that you need the texinfo source for every package you want documentation for, which is a pain especially for preinstalled packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a local web server you can use `info2www`.

`dwww` is a frontend for `info2www` (and some other packages) that lets you  search and read all sorts of local docs (including info and man pages) via a local web server.

Comment: Thanks! I also needed to follow the steps here https://askubuntu.com/questions/581118/i-cant-get-dwww-to-work-keeps-getting-404-not-found in order to get dwww to work.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, KDE's Konqueror and Rekonq browsers can display info pages directly, by exposing them through the `info:` protocol.

Simply launch Konqueror or Rekonq, and type e.g. "info:ls" in the address bar to access the info page for `ls`.

`man` pages are supported in the same way, via the `man:` protocol.

<sup><sup><sup>(cross-posted from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/271396/4830)</sup></sup></sup>