# How do I invoke the sqlite3-doc package

Tags: sqlite3

I installed the package but can't figure out how to use/start it. What I'm am looking for is a interactive help/docs for sqlite3 I assumed that what this package does but I don't know how to start it.

Thanks in addvance.

Comment: Next. 
Search in https://packages.ubuntu.com/

Example for sqlite3-doc: https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/all/sqlite3-doc/filelist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the description shown in `apt-cache show sqlite3-doc`:

> This package contains the documentation that is also available on
>    the SQLite homepage.

And appropriately enough, `apt-file show sqlite3-doc` will tell you that the package contains whole lot of `.html` pages stored in `/usr/share/doc/sqlite3-doc` directory. Now, you can either read those via the browser, or alternatively, as explained in a [related answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/52419/295286), you can install `dwww` package,  open the browser and point to `http://localhost/dwww`. This requires enabling `cgi` via `sudo a2enmod cgi` and restarting apache service `sudo systemctl restart apache2` ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/611864/295286)).

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for since I wanted to know how to invoke it when I'm offline.

Comment: @Sruly  Glad I could help. Since all `.html` files are located on your hard drive, they are in fact available off-line, either if you use `dwww` or `xdg-open` method, although `dwww` is a bit nicer for navigation

Answer (score 2):

You can just point your web browser at the index page

```
xdg-open /usr/share/doc/sqlite3-doc/index.html
```

and navigate the documentation from there.

Comment: This is a great answer but I was looking to be able to do it when I'm offline. Thanks.